# Finding idle Virtual Machines and deallocating them using Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine, azure-monitoring

I am creating an Azure Function that will find Virtual Machines that are idle or not in use to deallocate them. The Azure Function is now able to find **all** the Virtual Machines that are running and is able to deallocate them.

Now, how do I find if the VM is idle or no process running or no user is logged in? or any other parameter.

- I tried to Run Command for finding CPU usage, but somehow it failed to execute (maybe due to permission issue);
- I tried to Get Data from Azure Monitor > Metrics - Failed to do so.
- Tried finding in Documentations, didn't get any relevant results.

```cs
[FunctionName("DeallocateVM")]
public static void DeallocateVM([TimerTrigger("0 0 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(ClientId, ClientSecret, TenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
    var azure = Azure.Configure().WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic).Authenticate(credentials).WithDefaultSubscription();
    var VirtualMachinesList = azure.VirtualMachines.List();
    foreach (var Vm in VirtualMachinesList)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"{Vm.Name}\t{Vm.ProvisioningState}\t{Vm.PowerState}\t{Vm.ResourceGroupName}\t{Vm.OSType}\t{Vm.OSDiskSize}");
        if (Vm.PowerState == PowerState.Running)
        {
            if (Vm.IsIdle())
                Vm.DeallocateAsync(); //Deallocate the VM
        }
    }
}
static bool IsIdle(this IVirtualMachine virtualMachine)
{
    return true; //How to find a VM is idle or not?
}
```

I expect only the Idle VMs to be deallocated but currently, all the Vms are deallocated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftcomputevirtualmachines does this help ?

Comment: Thanks, @HariHaran - I saw the section `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines` - For the `Percentage CPU`. But I am unable to figure out how to use C# to get the data like `Percentage CPU` or `Disk Read Operations/Sec` or `Network Out`?

Comment: added a answer let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `metrics` using the `Monitor SDK`. Example :

```
var serviceCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(azureTenantId, azureAppId, azureSecretKey).Result;
MonitorClient monitorClient = new MonitorClient(serviceCreds) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
var resourceUrl = $"subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{machineName}";
var metricNames = "(name.value eq 'Disk Write Operations/Sec' or  name.value eq 'Percentage CPU' or  name.value eq 'Network In' or  name.value eq 'Network Out' or  name.value eq 'Disk Read Operations/Sec' or  name.value eq 'Disk Read Bytes' or  name.value eq 'Disk Write Bytes')"; 
 string timeGrain = " and timeGrain eq duration'PT5M'";
 string startDate = " and startTime eq 2017-10-26T05:28:34.919Z";
 string endDate = " and endTime eq 2017-10-26T05:33:34.919Z";
 var odataFilterMetrics = new ODataQuery<MetricInner>(
                $"{metricNames}{timeGrain}{startDate}{endDate}");

 var metrics = monitorClient.Metrics.ListWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceUrl, odataFilterMetrics).Result;
```

Comment: From which Namespace/Nuget reference can I get `MonitorClient`, `MetricInner` and `ODataQuery` class?

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor;

Comment: I was able to add DLL reference `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.dll` for monitor client, and it worked but now I am unable to find a reference for `MetricInner`. I changed `MetricInner` to `Metric` for now

Comment: I got the 200 response code. Now I am trying to debug the data I have received.

Comment: is there any nuget to use MonitorClient in .netcore 3.1 ?